How to convert expo-calendar recurrenceRule to rrule string
I got the RecurrenceRule from expo-calendar, the format is:
type RecurrenceRule = {
frequency: string
interval?: number // @default 1
endDate?: string | Date
occurrence?: number
daysOfTheWeek?: DaysOfTheWeek[]
daysOfTheMonth?: number[]
monthsOfTheYear?: MonthOfTheYear[]
weeksOfTheYear?: number[]
daysOfTheYear?: number[]
setPositions?: number[]

};
I want to convert it to RRule string. RRule format is:
const rule = new RRule({
    freq: number
    dtstart: Date | null;
    interval: number;
    wkst: Weekday | number | null;
    count: number | null;
    until: Date | null;
    tzid: string | null;
    bysetpos: number | number[] | null;
    bymonth: number | number[] | null;
    bymonthday: number | number[] | null;
    bynmonthday: number[] | null;
    byyearday: number | number[] | null;
    byweekno: number | number[] | null;
    byweekday: ByWeekday | ByWeekday[] | null;
    bynweekday: number[][] | null;
    byhour: number | number[] | null;
    byminute: number | number[] | null;
    bysecond: number | number[] | null;
    byeaster: number | null;
  });

Here i can convert some of options myself.
co
nst { frequency, interval, occurrence, endDate } = recurrenceRule;

  let options = {
    freq: RRule[frequency],
    interval,
  };

  if (endDate) {
    options.until = new Date(endDate);
  }
  if (occurrence) {
    options.count = occurrence;
  }
  const rule = new RRule(options);

but I can't sure how to parse for other option values. How can i parse it?
Please provide me if you know any module or sample code.
